# Submit button is not working with HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Whenever I attempt to click the submit button, nothing happens.

I have attempted to change the button, however I doubt this is the issue.

JavaScript Code:

```
$('#contactForm').submit(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/contact.php",
            data: $('#contactForm').serialize(),
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg == 'SEND') {
                    $('.success').fadeIn();
                    $('.error').fadeOut();
                    $('#contactForm')[0].reset();
                } else {
                    $('.success').fadeOut();
                    $('.error').fadeIn().find('h3').text(msg);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

HTML Code:

```
<div>
            <h2 class="small-heading">CONTACT US</h2>

            <div class="contact-form col-sm-11 clearfix">

                <form action="contact-complete.php" id="contactForm" method="post" name="contactForm">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name*" type="text" value="">
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email*" type="text" value="">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <textarea cols="5" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your Message....*"></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <button type="submit" form="contactForm" class="submit active">SEND</button>

                        </div>

                        <div class="error col-xs-12">
                            <h3></h3>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Error Message [ END ] -->

                        <div class="success col-xs-12" id="update">
                            <h3>Success! Your message was sent.</h3>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Submit Button [ END ] -->

                    </fieldset>
                </form>

                <!-- Contact Form [ END ] -->

            </div>
        </div>
```

If you could please help me out this would be much appreciated.

Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: Are you sure you're loading the JS? Try to put an `alert('hello')`

Comment: Yes, the JavaScript is loading. There are other scripts running on the page without a problem.

Comment: Is the Javascript inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Yes the JavaScript is nested within $(document).ready()

Comment: And what's supposed to happen, you know you're returning `false` so the form won't submit, and not handling ajax errors, so nothing happens if it fails.

Comment: You are using jQuery. Do you have the jQuery library loaded?

Comment: @Squeakasaur - if it wasn't included, or the DOM wasn't ready, *something* would happen, the form would submit and the page would redirect ?

Comment: @adeneo that was exactly the issue. I removed return false and it is now functioning correctly.

Comment: But if you remove the `return false` the form submits, and the ajax request, not to mention the entire event handler, is useless?

Comment: You're right. I'm kind of stuck. Return true? I'll try it out.

Comment: No, you want to return `false`, but your ajax request probably fails, otherwise the stuff in the `success` handler would execute. Add an error handler

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6jj9bf01/

Comment: @adeneo—why not post an answer *here*?

Comment: The AJAX request is sending the information successfully to my PHP mail() script without the return, however it's sending it twice.

Comment: @RobG - cause I have no idea what the real problem is, other than it's most likely the ajax call not succeeding?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue within the AJAX call. I removed "return false;" from the code and it seemed to work. However, it was sending the information twice. So I just removed the AJAX code all together and it worked just fine redirecting to the PHP mail() script.

Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: You should either post an answer as an answer, or delete the question.

Comment: I did post it as an answer, smarty pants. Stackoverflow has stated that I should not delete the question as it will stop others from learning. I told you what the fix was. I don't get why you must be so cynical, take a chill pill Rob.

Comment: It seems more like a comment to me. If you've removed the entire AJAX part then you're just doing a standard form submit so is there really any value to the question? Your choice of course. You can also accept your own answer so others know you're not seeking further answers.

Answer (score -1):

Your button doesnt have an action and you don´t listen for it either

```
<button type="submit" form="contactForm" class="submit active" OnClick="submit()">SEND</button>
```

Or add an ID and listen for that in the JS

Comment: Thank you, however I am already listening for an ID. @adeneo answered my problem. :-)

Comment: A submit button will submit the form without any scripting. When it's in a form, its form attribute references the form by default, even if it has no name or ID.

Comment: Yeah, i was a bit to fast there. I always use something like

<button id="#MyId" />
$("#MyId").click(function(){//stuff}

To avoid issues with unwanted form submit...